# Month and year wise display date in descending order

Tags: angularjs, date, mean-stack

In My monogdb I have Date column. I want to display the date in descending order with month and year wise. Date column:

`14-03-2018
12-03-2018
13-03-2018
11-03-2018
10-02-2018
06-01-2018
09-01-2018
08-02-2018
07-01-2017`

Expected result:

`14-03-2018
13-03-2018
12-03-2018
11-03-2018
10-02-2018
08-02-2018
09-01-2018
07-01-2017`

I used **tr dir-paginate date on dates orderBy:'LastFollowupDate':'desc'"** but is displaying what I expect

How to achieve this in angularjs

Comment: Not to enough details

Comment: orderby date,month,year in descending order

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $scope.sortDate= function(dt) {
    var date = new Date(dt);
    return date;
};
```

and

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th>date</th>            
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="date in dates | orderBy : sortDate : true">
            <td>{{date}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

[**DEMO**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWZePX)

Comment: demo site is not reaching

Answer (score 0):

LastFollowDate has date: 14-03-2018

```
var Sort_date=$scope.GetInformations[i].LastFollowDate.split('-');//split date
                                    $scope.$scope.GetInformations[i].oderdate= Sort_date[2]+Sort_date[1]+Sort_date[0];
```

The above code used to consider the whole number.
It will consider as number like 20180314. if the date is 15-03-2018 it will consider as number like 20180315. It will increase the number count. So If I want to display the previous date using descending order **ng-repeat**

> orderBy:'oderdate':'desc'